# rails database where query with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make a db query in my Controller with a where statement as params.
How do I do that?

example:

```
def show
@user = User.where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
end
```

It's a GET request and the parameters are :user_id.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this query? Your code doesn't have logical end so it's hard to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the meaning of "where statement as params" but if you're in `UsersController` and want to find the user given `params[:user_id]` then this should get you there.

```
def show
  @user = User.where(:id => params[:user_id])
end
```

If you don't need to use where you can just do

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

If neither of those work could you try to elaborate a little on what you are trying to accomplish and what you've tried so far?